# spring boot mybatis with redis as cache

Tags: spring, caching, spring-boot, redis, mybatis

I'm using Spring Boot with Mybatis, and I noticed that everytime I fetch some data with the same query, it will connect to db and query without using cache. So I search the solution for Mybatis with Redis, but cannot find one. All the answer is for Spring and xml configuration file, and I think it's better to use annotation. So, how to configure Redis as Cache to Mybatis in Spring Boot.

here is one of my solution, it just doesn't work.

**MybatisRedisCache:**

```
public class MybatisRedisCache implements Cache {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MybatisRedisCache.class);

private Jedis redisClient = createClient();

/** The ReadWriteLock. */
private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

private String id;
public MybatisRedisCache(final String id) {
    if (id == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cache instances require an ID");
    }
    logger.debug("MybatisRedisCache:id=" + id);
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return Integer.valueOf(redisClient.dbSize().toString());
}

@Override
public void putObject(Object key, Object value) {
    logger.debug("putObject:" + key + "=" + value);
    redisClient.set(SerializeUtil.serialize(key.toString()), SerializeUtil.serialize(value));
}

@Override
public Object getObject(Object key) {
    Object value = SerializeUtil.unserialize(redisClient.get(SerializeUtil.serialize(key.toString())));
    logger.debug("getObject:" + key + "=" + value);
    return value;
}

@Override
public Object removeObject(Object key) {
    return redisClient.expire(SerializeUtil.serialize(key.toString()), 0);
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    redisClient.flushDB();
}

@Override
public ReadWriteLock getReadWriteLock() {
    return readWriteLock;
}

protected  static Jedis createClient() {
    try {
        JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "127.0.0.1");
        return pool.getResource();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("connect failed");
}
```

}

And here is **LoggingRedisCache**

```
public class LoggingRedisCache extends LoggingCache {
public LoggingRedisCache(String id) {
    super(new MybatisRedisCache(id));
}
}
```